# Help recovering BitPay wallet Reward!

Tags: wallet-recovery, passphrase, bitpay

I had money sent to my wallet and couldn’t remember my encrypt password.  I had my 12 word recovery phrase written down but it’s abbreviated. I deleted my wallet which I shouldn’t have done because I’m sure I would have figured out the encrypt password by now and I’m going crazy with this recovery phrase. The way I store is 6 rows 2 words per row. 1st problem is I don’t know the order, it could go: left right left right... left right right left.... right left right...right left left right.  6 of the words I’m 100%.  4 words have 3 possible options. 1 has 2 options and the last could be a number of things.  I have the address that I had the money sent to (probably doesn’t help).  I know the name of the wallet (sure that doesn’t mean shit)     At this point I’m sure if I just knew the first and last word(the order) I’d figure it out.  I’d pay someone if I wasn’t certain they would take it plus how would they figure it out.  I’ve seen people that charge 10% but why wouldn’t they take it all? What can I do?   Is there a way to know which of my first two words are first

Answer (score 4):

> What can I do?

You could find tools that automate the trying of various combinations of seed-words. Some are mentioned in similar questions here. For example btctools, btcrecover. Use them or adapt them to your needs.

- [Lost my Bitcoin wallet and have only 11 out of 12 mnemonic seed phrase words. How can I get my Bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78987/13866)
- [Need help to recover blpckchain.info wallet, my wife forgot her password and the brute force with btcrecover is not catching the password](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/77209/13866)

I would

- Not involve other people in this.
- Not use software I can't build from source code I read and understand.
- Not use the software on a computer that is connected to any network.

If I had no success after a solid year of trying every day, I'd consider handing the problem over to a third party I had very thoroughly vetted.

Obviously if the wallet contains $3.65 or some other trivial amount - just forget about it, the time is not worth spending on this.

Comment: I looked at that but am not finding where to generate the different combinations

Comment: @Ryan. I don't think it will be easy. It may take some hard work on your part over a period of days, weeks or longer. Only you know whether the amount of money at stake justifies you investing more than 5 minutes of your time in looking at the tools and how to use them.

Comment: Let me ask you this. Is there a way to know which of my first two words is first? I seen For example, Satoshi Dice would always start with dice

Comment: @Ryan: not as far as I know. I believe any of the words in the dictionary can appear in any of the positions in the phrase.